# parsing xml from an api with simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, api

I'm trying to parse some data from the World Bank api in a php document.  I'm using simplexml_load_file to get the xml from a url like this: http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/IT.NET.BBND.P3?per_page=100&date=1981:2010

But I can't seem to output the data, I'm trying to use a foreach loop like here:

`$requestUrl = "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/IT.NET.BBND.P3?per_page=100&date=1981:2010";`

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($requestUrl);

foreach($xml->data as $i) {
    echo $i->country;
    echo $i->date;
    echo $i->value;
}
```

From the reading that I've done this should work but it doesn't, please can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. What happens or doesn't happen? What errors do you get?

Comment: Can you do `print_r($xml);` right before your foreach and post the output here? Also, what error do you get when you try the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$ns='wb';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($requestUrl);

foreach($xml->children($ns,true) as $i) {
    echo $i->country;
    echo $i->date;
    echo $i->value;
}

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php (see: Example #2 Using namespaces)